# Qt 5, QCamera, video streaming by network

Tags: c++, qt, video-streaming, video-capture, qtmultimedia

Can you guys help me, what the best way for streaming video and sound from webcam over network? I have a problem, because i'm need to use Qt for that. Now i'm using QCamera and QVideoWidget just for show videostream to screen, but i need to send this stream to server, which will show this stream to QVideoWidget too. May be need to use QMediaRecorder for that, but i'm not see some methods, where i can get audio/video raw-data frame, or may be other, anyway, how do you see for this, what the best way for streaming. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I found this solution: QCamera needs viewfinder for well working, and we can set viewfinder as QAbstractVideoSurface. So, we need to implement this base class and set up our implementation to viewfinder of camera. For that we need override start, stop and present methods. I did it, but now i have new porblems: application is crashing and it's not segfault... damn :)

Comment: solved. I had problems with my camera hardware.